# ArchLinux live iso, can ping google.com but not archlinux.org

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux

When pinging [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) theres no error and the command prints  `PING google.com (172.217.12.206) 56(84) bytes of data.`  But when pinging [www.archlinux.org](http://www.archlinux.org), ping prints   `ping: www.archlinux.org: name or service not known`

Comment: Ive tried changing my dns but the same error occurred.

Comment: Try running `nslookup` on the site and see what it resolves to.

Comment: it was most likely a dns error but it only occured on the liveiso, there was a mirror that did work and let me install. but when i logged into the new install and set up wifi it worked

Comment: Are you ping from *home*? Are you running any *firewall*? Did you check out your *access point*? Please, *ping* and *traceroute* the address *www.achlinux.org* and add their outputs to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Ping by default uses the ICMP protocol. DoS and DDoS attacks are mostly done using ICMP or UDP protocol. So many web hosting providers configure their client's websites to not respond to ICMP or UDP ping requests.

If you can't even access the website from your browser, then your DNS server or the site itself could be down. If your name server is assigned by the DHCP server (usually your router) then you can change it to a working DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

While it is common that a server won't respond to ICMP ping, this sounds like a DNS issue, considering that it's not even able to resolve `archlinux.org` into an IP. Which DNS server are you using? I'm willing to bet that it works if you use a different one. A few DNS servers worth memorizing:

- 4.2.2.2
- 4.2.2.1
- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4

For the record, archlinux.org resolves to `138.201.81.199` for IPv4 and `2a01:4f8:172:1d86::1` for IPv6 at my place.